# Cannot resolve symbol ‘PhoneWindow’ in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I find this class `phonewindow` in Andriod Studio, but i not found it.
Where i can find it? What should i do. Any help is appreciated.  As shown in picture：
[image]

Comment: how did you get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

PhoneWindow is not a class that is part of the public API of the Android SDK. You cannot reference it directly in your code.

Comment: Thanks.I finally find id in sdk\sources\android-23\com\android\internal\policy.